# Correct form of indefinite article (a, an) in PHP strings

Tags: php, string, cakephp

Is there an easy way to substitute a/an in a string to agree with the following word - much the same as the way 'S' works in Date format?

e.g.

```
$apple = 'apple';
$pear = 'pear';
echo "This is a $apple, this is a $pear."

--> This is an apple, this is a pear
```

Comment: This sounds like a preg_replace using a conditional regular expression.  See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: This can NEVER fully work :) English here has too many pitfalls. E.g. `A University` is the correct form even though the word starts with a `u`. Same with `an H...` in a lot of cases, if the consonant is silent and not spoken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
$l = array('a apple is a fruit', 'a banana is also a fruit');

foreach($l as $s) {
  $s = preg_replace('/(^| )a ([aeiouAEIOU])/', '$1an $2', $s);
  echo $s,"\n";
}
```

output:

```
an apple is a fruit
a banana is also a fruit
```

Comment: needed to use [aeiouAEIOU] as it is for a title where the significant words are capitalised. Thanks.

Comment: Right, i added the uppercase letters.

Comment: An university spent a hour researching a SO answer to find things wrong with it...

Answer (score 8):

Check this out, it passed my own testing, seems pretty solid.

https://github.com/Kaivosukeltaja/php-indefinite-article

Answer (score 7):

You could use a regular expression to swap the a/and depending on what follows it. The trickier part will actually be defining all of the cases on which to swap - it is more complicated then 'if its followed by a vowel'.

**When to use a/an:**

Use a before words/abbreviations that begin with a consonant sound; use an before words/abbreviations that begin with a vowel sound. This is based on pronunciation, not spelling.

Hence:

- a university
- an hour
- an ytterbium molecule
- a yellow dog
- a U
- an M

**Beginning of a regex to solve it**

```
$text = preg_replace("/(?=a|e|i|o|u|yt)a/", "an", $text);
```

Comment: the regex is wrong. it asserts beginning in the position of an a.

Comment: Bah, my point was the language rather than the regex/function used, which is pretty simple. Doing a basic swap according to whether 'a' is followed by a vowel just isn't the correct form of an indefinite article.

Comment: You've made some interesting points. Common usage is the key to this. An hotel is correct, but actual usage and pronunciation depends on where in the country (England) you come from, amongst other things. Therefore a hotel is equally correct. Making other distinctions, e.g. a university, an umbrella is not easily done algorithmically.

Comment: I was looking in to this issue recently, and came to the same difficulty with pronunciation: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19085/indefinite-article-a-an

Answer (score 3):

not sure if it works in PHP that way but a really simple solution would be:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\ba\b\s([aeiou])/',   'an $1', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/\ban\b\s([^aeiou])/', 'an $1', $string);
```

(Not sure about the a/an rule as there is no such rule in german and i usually use the one that sounds better)

Explanation:

\b is a word boundary, so \ba\b looks for the word a, followed by a space and one of the letters [aeiou]. The letter is captured to $1 and the expression is replaced with `an` followed by the captured letter.

Comment: Thanks - equal first place with M42.

Answer (score 1):

I've forked the module Luke Chavers refers to, cleaning it up, fixing a logic error and making it integrable using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org); with that installed, you can pull it into your project with:

```
php composer.phar require thaumatic/indefinite-article
```

The source code is at https://github.com/thaumatic/indefinite-article.

Answer (score 0):

I used Luke Chaver's answer to write a quick and nasty php snippet to do handle this

```
<?php
//code inspired by https://github.com/Kaivosukeltaja/php-indefinite-article/blob/master/IndefiniteArticle.class.php
global $indef_A_abbrev, $indef_A_y_cons, $indef_A_explicit_an, $indef_A_ordinal_an, $indef_A_ordinal_a;

$indef_A_abbrev = "(?! FJO | [HLMNS]Y.  | RY[EO] | SQU
          | ( F[LR]? | [HL] | MN? | N | RH? | S[CHKLMNPTVW]? | X(YL)?) [AEIOU])
            [FHLMNRSX][A-Z]
        ";
$indef_A_y_cons = 'y(b[lor]|cl[ea]|fere|gg|p[ios]|rou|tt)';
$indef_A_explicit_an = "euler|hour(?!i)|heir|honest|hono";
$indef_A_ordinal_an = "[aefhilmnorsx]-?th";
$indef_A_ordinal_a = "[bcdgjkpqtuvwyz]-?th";

function indefinite_article($input){
    global $indef_A_abbrev, $indef_A_y_cons, $indef_A_explicit_an, $indef_A_ordinal_an, $indef_A_ordinal_a;
    $word = preg_replace("^\s*(.*)\s*^", "$1", $input);
    if(preg_match("/^[8](\d+)?/", $word)) {
        return "an $word";
    }
    if(preg_match("/^[1][1](\d+)?/", $word) || (preg_match("/^[1][8](\d+)?/", $word))) {
        if(strlen(preg_replace(array("/\s/", "/,/", "/\.(\d+)?/"), '', $word))%3 == 2) {
            return "an $word";
        }
    }
    if(preg_match("/^(".$indef_A_ordinal_a.")/i", $word))       return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^(".$indef_A_ordinal_an.")/i", $word))      return "an $word";
    if(preg_match("/^(".$indef_A_explicit_an.")/i", $word))         return "an $word";
    if(preg_match("/^[aefhilmnorsx]$/i", $word))        return "an $word";
    if(preg_match("/^[bcdgjkpqtuvwyz]$/i", $word))      return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^(".$indef_A_abbrev.")/x", $word))          return "an $word";
    if(preg_match("/^[aefhilmnorsx][.-]/i", $word))         return "an $word";
    if(preg_match("/^[a-z][.-]/i", $word))          return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^[^aeiouy]/i", $word))                  return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^e[uw]/i", $word))                      return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^onc?e\b/i", $word))                    return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^uni([^nmd]|mo)/i", $word))     return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^ut[th]/i", $word))                     return "an $word";
    if(preg_match("/^u[bcfhjkqrst][aeiou]/i", $word))   return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^U[NK][AIEO]?/", $word))                return "a $word";
    if(preg_match("/^[aeiou]/i", $word))            return "an $word";
    if(preg_match("/^(".$indef_A_y_cons.")/i", $word))  return "an $word";
    return "a $word";
}

$words = array(
    "historical",
    "hour",
    "wholesale",
    "administrator",
    "inner circle"
);
foreach ($words as $word) {
    echo indefinite_article($word);
    echo "\n";
}

?>
```