# How to add dynamic a or an to the numeric value

Tags: php, numbers, prefix

I need to add dynamic prefixes a or an in front of numbers by their pronunciation( eg: a one-part section, an eight-digit number )

Eg: 1 - a 1-digit number.

```
11 - an 11 number of items in the box
```

Comment: Where is your proof of research and toil? Here is a related page that gives HORRIBLE advice: [Add prefix (a or an) to a word using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23933910/2943403)  A mix of bad and not-so-bad advice can be found here: [Correct form of indefinite article (a, an) in PHP strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3576162/2943403)  Slightly more considered advice here: [Programmatically determine whether to describe an object with "a" or "an"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4558437/2943403)